# Cassini service keeps crashing

Tags: .net, iis, cassini

I'm running XP home which doesn't support IIS. Therefore i'm running Cassini.

It usually works well. How ever i've notice in the last 2 weeks it crashes. I'm guessing there is some conflict. Perhaps something i've installed recently tho i can't work out what.

How can i work what is conflicting, also i've read about running it on a different port that 80. How would i set this up? Or maybe it's something else?

thanks.

```
##### error 1 ######


Exception in Cassini web application [11692, "CWS"].
Exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Cassini.Server.Start()
   at CassiniService.Service1.WebAppEntry.Start()

For more information, see Help and Support Center at 

##### error 2 ################


Faulting application ultidevcassinwebserver2a.exe, version 2.1.0.3, stamp 45caafc1, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5781, stamp 49c4f482, debug? 0, fault address 0x00012afb.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run:

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

you will get a list of what is running on each port.

This list includes the PID (process id) you can then use task manager to find which process is on port 80.